# What is the right way to look at tensor products?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Here tensor products are defined for modules over a commutative ring $A$ with identity. I have only encountered tensor products in linear algebra(where the multilinearty of determinants naturally leads to the definition of tensor products.) But I didn’t have any idea how “powerful” this object will be. Recently I came up with a way to look at it when I am studying commutative algebra:

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and $I$ an ideal of $A$. Given a left $A$-module $M$ we would “**modify**” $M$ so that it becomes a module over the quotient ring $A/I$. It turns out $M/IM$ is the module we are looking for, with the naturally induced $A/I$-module structure defined by $$(a+I)(m+IM)=am+IM.$$ This is useful when $I$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, because then we have a naturally induced vector space $M/IM$ over the field $A/I$. But using tensor products, we obtain another way to look at $M/IM$: $$(A/I)\otimes_A M\simeq M/IM.$$ In other words, the tensor product in this case is the “**modification**” we need.

As I understand, tensor products in this case simplify a lot when we study local rings and we only need to consider the algebraic properties of tensor products.

Are there any other perspectives to look at tensor products? (not limited to just algebra) At what other place will it be powerful?

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to claim anything definite for I haven't taught tensor product to very many. Those that I have quite appreciated the example that if $k$ is a field, then we have a very natural isomorphism
$$k[x]\otimes_k k[x]\cong k[x,y].$$ This was over a field, but the same holds over any commutative ring as the modules are free in this case.

Comment: Oh, and if/when you get into representations of finite groups, then induction (from a subgroup to the supergroup) is easiest to explain using a tensor product over a group algebra.

Comment: @Jyrki I'm probably not pure mathematician enough, but to me your equation becomes much more tangible in the form $k^a\otimes k^b =k^{a\times b}$

Comment: (which makes perfect sense next to $k^a\oplus k^b=k^{a+b}$)